# desactivar checkboxes con al presionar uno cuando son dinamicos en react

Tags: reactjs

Tengo una columna con checkbox de una tabla que se llena dinamicamente

```
{this.state.roomsinforate[idx].map((item, index) => (
  <tbody key={index}>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="check-form">
          <input
            name="check"
            id={'check'}
            data-idx={idx}
            data-index={index}
            checked={this.state.checked[idx + index]}
            onClick={this.Handlecheck}
            type="checkbox"
          ></input>
        </div>
      </td>
      <th scope="row">{item.room_category_desc}</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
))}
```

Lo que necesito hacer es que cuando se seleccione uno de los checkbox se seleccione los demas se desactiven.

Comment: ¿no lograrías eso de mejor manera usando un `type="radio"` en vez de un `type="checkbox"`?, me refiero, solo uno puede ser seleccionado ¿cierto?. Porque si seleccionas uno, los demás se desactivan, pero si quieres seleccionar otro, deberías deseleccionar el seleccionado y de ahí seleccionar otro... no se si me doy a entender, pero se me hace un poco engorroso y con un radio button creo que quedaría más intuitivo... opinión personal.

Comment: En teoría si es el funcionamiento que necesito pero al ser un radio no puedo dar un clic para des seleccionarlo y con lo cual necesito ejecutar una acción diferente por lo que no me funciona el radio.